# How to ignore warnings from static third party libraries in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, static-libraries

I have to integrate a third party library (.a) in my iOS application (ios 11).

The thing is: compiler produces more than 200 warnings related to this library. Developer company responsible for this library refuses to fix it but I have to integrate this. It breaks the CI, mess up the project and drive us crazy due to the overloading of warnings.

Any ideas on how to dismiss these warnings from this specific library?